# Retrieving Bitnami Wordpress Multisite 'user' password from an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have misplaced my default 'user' password for logging into my Bitnami Wordpress Multi-site web UI.

I have tried the solutions mentioned at: [docs.bitnami.com](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/starting-bitnami-aws/find_credentials/#option-2-find-password-by-connecting-to-your-application-through-ssh) to retrieve it via the 'System Log' in the AWS Console but it is no longer there.

I am also trying to retrieve it via **SSH** as described below.

**Option 2:** Find Password By Connecting To Your Application Through SSH
The application credentials are also stored in your application files. To obtain the password at any time, follow these instructions:

Connect to the application through SSH.
Run the following command to see your application credentials:

```
cat ./bitnami_credentials
```

In case that you can not see the content of the above file, check the following:

```
sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/data/bitnami_credentials/credentials
```

I am able to SSH into my bitnami EC2 instance but none of the above commands work to show me the password for the standard 'user'.

I am currently running Wordpress 4.7.11

Please help. :)

Comment: Guessing neither of the files `bitnami_credentials` \ `credentials` exist which seems strange if it's a bitnami image and the docs state that.  Can you `cd` in /opt/bitnami/var/data/bitnami_credentials ?

Comment: No unfortunately not, when im in `/opt/bitnami/var`, i need to `sudo su` to get into `data`. Then the `data` directory then shows as empty.

Comment: Have you tried this "If the Bitnami banner is not visible, the same information can also be accessed by browsing to http://SERVER-IP-ADDRESS:PORT/bitnami.": https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/starting-bitnami-aws/find_credentials/

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

The default password in our installations is 'bitnami', then we generate a random one and configure the application again during the boot process of the machine. If the boot process didn't finish properly, it probably didn't change the password of the app, can you try using user/bitnami? If that works, please change the password of the application as soon as possible.

In order to obtain more information about how the deployment finished, can you share with us the content of the logs at `/opt/bitnami/var/log/*`? In the pre-start.log file you can also find the password of the application.

Thanks